# Use text passages including references of one .tex file in another .tex file

Tags: xr, clipboard

I (teacher at university) plan to create a questionnaire based on the following MWE `questionnare.tex`. The important point is that some of the questions refer to each other.

```latex
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{clipboard}
\newclipboard{questionnaire}

\newcommand{\newquestionaire}[2]{{
    \section{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),itemsep=-2pt]
        #2
    \end{enumerate} }}
\newcommand\itemtext[2]{%
    \expandafter\gdef\csname item#1\endcsname{#2}%
    \label{#1}
    \Copy{#1}{#2}}

\newcommand{\question}[2]{\item \itemtext{#1}{#2}}

\begin{document}

\section*{Questionnaire}

\newquestionaire{Weather}{
    \question{qu:1a}{How was the weather today?}
    \question{qu:1b}{How is the weather today?}
    \question{qu:1c}{Refering to the results of \ref{qu:1b}, how is the weather going to be tomorrow?}
}
\newquestionaire{Mood}{
    \question{qu:2a}{How is your mood today?}
    \question{qu:2b}{Refering to the results of \ref{qu:2a}, how is your mood going to be tomorrow?}
}

\end{document}
```

Now, based on the questions in `questionnaire.tex` I'd like to prepare a test including only some of the questions. At the moment for this purpose I am using `\Copy` and `\Paste` from the package `clipboard`. Here is the MWE of `test.tex`:

```latex
\documentclass[DIV=12]{scrartcl}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{clipboard}

\openclipboard{questionnaire}

\newcommand{\newquestionaire}[2]{{
    \section{#1}
    \begin{enumerate}[label=(\alph*),itemsep=-2pt]
        #2
    \end{enumerate} }}

\newcommand{\useQuestion}[1]{\item \Paste{#1}}


\begin{document}

\section*{TEST}

\newquestionaire{Weather}{
    \useQuestion{qu:1b}
    \useQuestion{qu:1c}
}

\end{document}
```

The problem is that after compiling `test.tex` the references are not properly resolved. Is there any possibility to use plain LaTeX text from one LaTeX file in another LaTeX file including references?